# How to set font style in qml rich format Text

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I'm using `SF Pro Text` fonts in the app. They are loaded from `main.cpp`:

```
id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/SF-Pro-Text-Light.otf");
id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf");
id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/SF-Pro-Text-Medium.otf");
```

In `main.qml` I can use `SF Pro Text Light` font using combination of font.family and font.styleName properties:

```
Text {
    text: "Some Text";
    font.family: "SF Pro Text"
    font.styleName: "Light"
}
```

font.styleName here can be set to Light/Medium/Regular.

But my goal is to create text line with few mixed font styles, so I tried to use the following approach:

```
Text {
    text: "<span style=\"font-family:SF Pro Text;\">
                Outer
                <span style=\"font-family:SF Pro Text;\">Inner Text</span>
                Text
           </span>";
    textFormat: Text.RichText
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand how can I pass style (medium, light or regular) inside the rich text. Could you please point me to the correct property in html or to a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: what about `font-style: light;`?

Comment: @folibis, that doesn't work. Supported values for `font-style` are: `[ normal | italic | oblique ]`

Comment: My workaround was to open fonts in FontLab tool and rename "family" properties to make them different. After that `font-family` was enough.

Comment: I think I'm confused. that should be `font-weight: light`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Here is a list of suported font-weight values in qt html subset: `[ normal | bold | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900 ]`. Applying them doesn't make font look like a Light :(